# Probabilities of classes using h2o.predict

Tags: regression, machine-learning, classification, random-forest

How does h2o.predict calculate the probabilities of different classes ? In the randomForest package of R, the probabilities are calculated based on the number of votes. For example probability of being class B = number of votes for class B / total number of trees. I can't seem to understand how h2o's RF algorithm provides so much granular probabilities even with few trees

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "so much granular probabilities". Can you clarify? perhaps giving some examples?

Comment: for example: if I use 5 trees in randomForest package, I get a max of 6 different probabilities (0,0.2,0.4,0.6,0.8,1) considering the different combination of votes. But in the case of h2o package, the unique probabilities are more than 100

Answer (score 1):

According to [this Google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/h2ostream/rRPcZiCzUQs)  Random Forest of H20 calculates probabilities at each leaf rather than calculating a vote. And the prediction is the average of probabilities instead of average of votes.

And according to [this benchmark](http://datascience.la/benchmarking-random-forest-implementations/) the Random Forest of H20 is more accurate than classical Random Forest (randomForest function in R and Random Forest in scikit-learn in Python).